# My character always fails me

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Are there any expressions or idioms in English that mean someone whose character always fails them?

For example: I believe in people but they often cheat me. Every time I promise myself that I won't believe them again, like "a leopard that never changes its spots", I believe them again.

So in this case, are the following appropriate?

> My personality / character / soft heartedness always fails me.

Comment: Without clarification "my personality fails me" is unclear, and doesn't mean what you are aiming for. You can say "I am too gullible", "I'm too soft", "I'm a softy at heart", "my problem is I trust people too much" or "I'm a pushover", it depends on what you want to convey and how negative you might feel about the situation.

Comment: What if I say "your laziness will fail you in life" I just want to make sure whether it is possible to use the verb " to fail" in those situations.

Comment: The sort of person you describe has sometimes been described as a 'loser', but that is an unsympathetic word and so may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: So the *real* question is how to use the verb "fail" in connection with personality traits? Is there a reason why it must be "to fail". Please provide more detail and clarify what it is exactly you are seeking help with.

Comment: No, "Your laziness will fail you in life" is not idiomatic English. One, slightly old-fashioned, way of expressing it is "Laziness is your besetting sin" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/besetting%20sin)

Comment: I just want to say about soft-hearted people who can never resist helping others, but consequently, it cause them problems. Just I don't know how to say it correctly.                               Maybe, my kindness always cause me trouble? ( but I don't know to be honest).

Comment: Put that last comment in the question, it clarifies what you are asking for. Did you look up any of the suggestions I posted at the beginning? Can you say why none of them fit, but always **in** the question.

Comment: Yes, I did you were right I wanted to use the verb " to fail" to express what I wanted to say.                           "My acts of kindness usually causes me trouble" I have been told by my friend whose native tongue is English.

Comment: If, as you write, a native English speaker has suggested the sentence *My acts of kindness usually causes me trouble* then you have been *suckered* again.  The verb in that sentence does not agree in number with its subject, instead you should think *My acts of kindness usually cause me trouble*.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion then, I'm really stuck, I am just unable to deliver what I exactly mean, in Russian we use the verb "подводит" For instance: "Мой характер всегда подводит меня"In English for people we use" let someone down" " put someone out", however this is about personality of someone which always is misused by other people, in the end we regret having this kind of personality! I am trying to fine a decent verb like above.

Answer (score 0):

The word *sucker* seems to fit the bill. Chambers online provides the definition

> someone who is gullible or who can be easily deceived or taken
>   advantage of

The word doesn't mean that the person's *character always fails them* which is what is asked for in the question.  But the trail of commentary clarifies that *sucker* covers at least most of what OP is looking for.  It's also a word widely used in this sense, it is not archaic nor recondite.